# Can we convert string that have more than one float to double in C

Tags: c

Can we use strtod for convert string ("1.234 34.345 245.356") to double? because when I use strtod it only convert the first number.

Comment: Check out `strtok()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how any standard conversion function is supposed to work.

However, if you read [the `strtod` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) you will see that is has an `str_end` argument, which is a pointer that can be initialized to the end of the parsed number in the string. You can use this pointer to parse the *next* number in the string.

For example something like this:

```
char string[] = "1.234 34.345 245.356";
char *next_number = string;

double number1 = strtod(next_number, &next_number);
double number2 = strtod(next_number, &next_number);
double number3 = strtod(next_number, NULL);
```

Comment: Couldn't you also just use `&next_number` for the 2nd argument in the 3rd statement?  (perhaps useful as a test eg in a looping construct.)

Comment: @ryyker Of course. I'm just showing how to work with a specific string, it can be modified to work with generic strings in a loop (but then null-pointer checks must be added).

Answer (score 0):

> *"Can we use strtod for convert string ("1.234 34.345 245.356") to double?"*

Yes, `strtod(...)` is designed for just that purpose.
The following illustrates reading any number of values from `stdin`, and parsing into array using `strtod(...)`.
(Usege of `strtok()`, in helper function provides count of inputs to use in creating dynamically sized array to store parsed numbers.)

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    double *array = NULL;
    int count = 0, i = -1;
    
    printf("%s", "Enter numbers separated with spaces, then <return>\n");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
    char *next_num = buffer;
    char *dup = StrDup(buffer);
    if(dup)
    {
        count = count_numbers(dup);
        array = calloc(count, sizeof(*array));
        if(array)
        {
            for(i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                array[i] = strtod(next_num, &next_num);
            }
            //use array
            //...
            free(array);
        }
        free(dup);
    }
    return 0;
}

int count_numbers(const char *nums)
{
    char *tok = NULL;
    char *delim = " \t\n,";
    int count = 0;
    tok = strtok(nums, delim);
    while(tok)
    {
        count++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have discussed `strtod`, and a comment mentions `strtok`.
Another possibility is `sscanf`:

```
char *str = "1.234 34.345 245.356";
double a, b, c;
int n = sscanf(str, "%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
printf("got %d values\n", n);
```